# Javascript creating variable with html code with a new date variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I do not understand what is wrong here:

```
var $newbox = $('<div class="ui-widget-content" id="newbox-'**+noteId**'" style="top:' + e.pageY + 'px; left: ' + e.pageX + 'px;"><span id="close">Delete comment</span><p>Your comment:</p><textarea></textarea></div>');
```

without this +noteId works just fine, with it firebug gives an error of missing ')'... btw thesse **** have been added so you can spot the error easier :)

here is the working code:

```
    function makeNote(e) {
    var noteDate = new date();
    var noteId = noteDate.getTime();
    // Check the event object if the .click is on the content
    // or a created note
    if (e.eventPhase === 2) {

        // Create the new comment at the corsor postition
        var $newbox = $('<div class="ui-widget-content" id="newbox" style="top:' + e.pageY + 'px; left: ' + e.pageX + 'px;"><button id="close" class="m-btn red"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button><button id="save" class="m-btn blue"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Save</button><textarea></textarea></div>');
        $('#content').append($newbox);
        if(!$newbox.draggable()){
            $newbox.draggable();
        }

    }

}

function deleteNote() {
    $(this).parent('#newbox').remove();
}

// wait until the dom document is loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // listen for a .click() event on the content element
    $('#content').on('click', function(e){
        makeNote(e);
    })

    // Remove the note
    $("button #close").on('click',function() {
        deleteNote();
    });

});
```

**UPDATE**
Also the deleteNote function does not work, that is why I have to make an unique id for each note, taking the time from the date gives an random number output...

**UPDATE2**
http://s1.postimg.org/41csvbanz/Screenshot_from_2015_06_07_13_27_15.png
http://s18.postimg.org/j5bowucwp/Screenshot_from_2015_06_07_13_27_28.png

Comment: Voting to close as off topic due to typos; you are missing a `+` after `noteId` and you failed to capitalize `Date`.

Comment: That's some brutal string literal HTML. Try using jQuery's [DOM element constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) to clean up your code. Also, the selector `button #close` is in poor form - an ID selector should only ever be the leftmost part of a selector, and there should only be one ID in a selector, as there is no selector more specific than the ID of the element. See: [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, so the function didn't worked but I figured it out:

```
$('button #close').on('click', function() {
$this.parent('#newbox').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`new date();` should be uppercase: `new Date();`